# disable permissions of other applications (no root)

Tags: android

I want to create an application which disable the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission of other application that are running on the device. 
The device is NOT rooted.
Is it possible to temporary disable permission  of other application (without root).
I searched a lot and it looks like this is not possible.

**Remark**: For rooted device I understand it is possible to disable permissions, by using Xposed similarly to how Xprivate is implemented. but as I said in my case the device is not rooted

Answer (score 0):

> I searched a lot and it looks like this is not possible.

Correct.

If this device runs Android 6.0+, the user can disable the relevant runtime permission in Settings.